# unable to update my records

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a form which is working fine to insert data in to database.

I'm trying to update record but it seems to have bit issue with my code.

When I submit update button its not showing any error, but when I see in my database the values are not getting updated.

Please can any one help me what issue might be in my code? Please it would be helpful for me.

**Controller:**

```
<?php
class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        //load database libray manually
        $this->load->database();

        //load Model
        $this->load->model('Form_model');

        // load form and url helpers
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        // load form_validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function updatedata()
    {
        $id=$this->input->get('id');
        $result['data']=$this->Form_model->displayrecordsById($id);
        $this->load->view('update_records',$result);    

        if($this->input->post('update'))
        {

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[form.username]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[form.email]');

            if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
            {
                $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/'; 
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if($this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
                {
                    $fn=$this->input->post('fname');
                    $ln=$this->input->post('lname');
                    $un=$this->input->post('username');
                    $em=$this->input->post('email');
                    $fi = $this->upload->data('file_name');
                    $this->Form_model->updaterecords($fn,$ln,$un,$em,$fi,$id);
                    echo 'Successfully updated your record';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Model:**

```
<?php
class Form_model extends CI_Model 
{
    //get values 
    function displayrecordsById($id){
        $query=$this->db->query("select * from form where ID='".$id."'");
        return $query->result();
    }

    //update record
    function updaterecords($fn,$ln,$un,$em,$fi,$id){
        $query=$this->db->query("update form SET first_name='$fn',last_name='$ln',username='$un',email='$em',filename='$fi' where ID='".$id."'");
    }
}
?>
```

**Display the records:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Display Records</title>
    </head>        
    <body>
        <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
            <tr style="background:#CCC">
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Update</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $i=1;
            foreach($data as $row)
            {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->first_name."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->last_name."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->username."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row->email."</td>";
                echo '<td><img src="' . base_url('uploads/' . $row->filename) . '" alt="image" width="100px" height="100px"></td>';
                echo "<td><a href='updatedata?id=".$row->ID."'>Update</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
            }
            ?>
        </table>            
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update the record:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration form</title>
    </head>        
    <body>
        <?php
        $i=1;
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">                
                <tr>
                    <td width="230">First name </td>
                    <td width="329"><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row->first_name; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td>Last name </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row->last_name; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td>Username </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $row->username; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td>E-mail </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row->email; ?>"/></td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td>Image</td>
                    <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/' . $row->filename);?>" class="img-responsive" alt="image" width="100px" height="100px"><br><input type="file" name="filename" value=""></td>
                </tr>                
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Records"/></td>
                </tr>                
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to narrow down what the problem is exactly and only post the relevant code.

Comment: sir i have pasted relavent code only sir

Comment: you forgot action in your form.

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?= base_url()?">

Answer (score 0):

**View**

```
echo "<td><a href='updatedata?id=".$row->ID."'>Update</a></td>";
```

You are passing values in url

**Controller**

```
public function updatedata($id)    
{    
    echo $id;    
}
```

**Tip:**
If you are using `<form method="post"` then always get data as `$this->input->post('value');` and try get for method get

**Please Note:**
Don't mix custom php with codeigniter try to read documentation for codeigniter syntax